# NSURLRequest HTTPBody truncated on server side

Tags: ios, node.js, http, tcp, nsurlrequest

Sending `NSData` though internet. Sent data lenght is **8278** byte. But received data is only **8029** byte. Do you know why data is truncated received by server? Is it any HTTP / TCP limit for size of the data? Or is it a `node.js` limitation?

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let path = (documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Assets") as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(upsert.recordName).\(field2.key)")

let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "xxx")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("image/jpg", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
request.setValue("\(upsert.recordName).\(field.key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "filename")
request.HTTPBody = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()).dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, urlResponse, error in }).resume()
```

Comment: Is the image received by the server, still a valid image - that is, the image is _not_ corrupt?

Comment: If it surprisingly turns out that the image is still valid, you may find this interesting: https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.5.7.2

Comment: You are right, middle nodes reduced the size, but data, content was not `json`, but `png` I guess, that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By removing

`request.setValue("image/jpg", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")`

line will prevent to reduce and convert content.

Comment: You should always set the content-type header according the actual kind of data. If you want to prevent a _transforming proxy_ to change the content-type you can set the cache control directive in your request, e.g. add a header: `Cache-Control: no-transform`. However, this may come at a cost, since proxies may choose to do this because of optimising performance and caches.

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-transform` has no effect in my case

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you just fixed what I've spent 3 hours debugging with that comment. Please add it as an answer so I can upvote!